# Pandas: How to put labels on timestamp based on pre-designated time interval?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---------------------+--------+
| time                | score  |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-01 08:01:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-01 15:01:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-02 23:45:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-03 09:32:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-04 20:01:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-04 16:30:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2021-01-04 12:01:00 | xx     |
+---------------------+--------+
```

I also have a **pre-designated time interval legend** that looks like this:

- 2AM - 5:59AM:  G1
- 6AM - 9:59AM:  G2
- 10AM - 4:29PM: G3
- 4:30PM - 7:29PM: G4
- 7:30PM - 7:59PM: G5
- 8PM - 10:59PM: G6
- 11PM - 1:59AM: G7

How do I **add a new column that assign labels to each timestamps** based on pre-designated time interval legend?

The final dataframe would look like this:

```
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| time                | score  | group |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 08:01:00 | xx     | G2    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 15:01:00 | xx     | G3    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-02 23:45:00 | xx     | G7    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-03 09:32:00 | xx     | G2    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-04 20:01:00 | xx     | G6    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-04 16:30:00 | xx     | G4    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-04 12:01:00 | xx     | G3    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the time with [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) and then [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html?highlight=cut#pandas.cut):

```
shifted_times = (df['time'] - pd.Timedelta('2H'))
int_times = shifted_times.dt.hour * 100 + shifted_times.dt.minute

df['group'] = pd.cut(int_times, right=False,
                bins = [99, 400, 800, 1430, 1730, 1800, 2100, 2400],
                labels=['G1','G2','G3','G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7']
              )
```

Output:

print(df)

```
                 time score group
0 2021-01-01 08:01:00    xx    G2
1 2021-01-01 15:01:00    xx    G3
2 2021-01-02 23:45:00    xx    G7
3 2021-01-03 09:32:00    xx    G2
4 2021-01-04 20:01:00    xx    G6
5 2021-01-04 16:30:00    xx    G4
6 2021-01-04 12:01:00    xx    G3
```

Comment: What's the reason for using the 2H shifted time? Is there a way to not use that 2H shift?